# Codename one, Capture Audio

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to record audio, I am using this example [codename one capture](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/capture/Capture.html).

I am getting error on this line

```
 Util.copy(fs.openInputStream(file), fs.openOutputStream(filePath));
```

Util class cannot find method `copy`
this is my code

```
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
String recordingsDir = fs.getAppHomePath() + "recordings/";
fs.mkdir(recordingsDir);
try {
    String file = Capture.captureAudio();
    if(file != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd-kk-mm");
            String fileName =sd.format(new Date());
            String filePath = recordingsDir + fileName; 
            Util.copy(fs.openInputStream(file), fs.openOutputStream(filePath)); //stuck here
   }
}catch(IOException err) {
        System.out.println(err);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the com.codename1.io.Util and not a Util class from a different package